# How to upgrade from 12.x to 14.x?

Tags: upgrade

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 from a CD in a book I just bought, but it, of course, is out of date. There should be an executable or an archive that I can pull to my hard drive, and open with the Archive Manager or the Software Updater.

***Please don't just give me another link!*** I've been Googling and linking all day.

I have gone to the upgrade page, and a file (ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) downloads, but I can't do anything with it. It's not an executable, and the archive manager looks, but doesn't install or run anything from it.

Please, what are the STEPS? as in:
1. download THIS from HERE
2. Put it in THIS-PLACE (under Home, or '/Root' or where??)
3. open it with UBUNTU-TOOL-A

*Rant follows here:*
My ultimate goal is just to get the Eclipse Java compiler running. To install it in *that other operating system*, I just downloaded and ran the install for the JDK and then downloaded the Eclipse zip file, extracted it, and BOOM, I was programming in Java.

I downloaded Eclipse for Ububtu, and it needs the JRE or JDK. I download the JDK, and it needs the JRE. I search for the JRE for Ubuntu, and the link takes me to the same page for the JDK.

Why is it so convoluted just to get what amounts to a software program to run here?

Comment: There is no easy path for you to upgrade as 13.04 and 13.10 are also beyond end of life. Rather then upgrade through 3 versions (12.10 -> 13.04 -> 13.10 -> 14.04) just do a fresh install. A fresh install is far faster and more reliable. As 12.10 , 13.04, and 13.10 are all beyond end of life, upgrading the way you envision is unsupported, thus there are no tutorials or tools.

Comment: If you want to upgrade rather than doing a fresh install, and if it is really not useful for us to link you to questions that already have answers about how to do it because those answers are not working for you, then in order for us to help you you'll have to tell us *all* about what you've tried, where you read about it, and what went wrong. In particular, if you  tried [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815), what happened? *That should work* to enable you to upgrade 12.10 Quantal to 13.04 (and so on). You can [edit] with details.

Comment: @jbrock
If a raw, fresh install is the way to go, then *NO PROBLEM*. I just installed today, so I have nothing built up to save, just the cost of the day lost fooling around with an obsolete build.

Answer (score 0):

The file you have downloaded is an iso. You should burn it to a DVD or create a live usb with startup disk creator. Click **[here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)** for deatils on creating bootable USB.

Now you can use the usb stick to upgrade your ubuntu by booting from it.

The best way is coneeting to internet and upgrading via Update manager. Click [**here**](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04) to know how.

Comment: This doesn't work, because it starts out looking for 'Quantal' stuff.
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]

I don't need an upgrade, I guess. I need a fresh install.
Thanks!

Comment: @user3063708 You can use the iso you have downloaded to install afresh copy of Ubuntu. See http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop for details.

Comment: That page tells how to install from a DVD (which I do not have) or from USB thumb drive, which my laptop will not do, as far as I can tell.

I will continue to try - perhaps if I actually have a bootable USB inserted, it will give me the option. I will give it a try.

Comment: I created the bootable USB, but my laptop will not boot from USB. All the suggested links to all the pages of instructions all fall short and leave me with large file downloaded that will not run. 'All you have to do is...' becomes, 'Not so fast... you need to run THIS utility to create the bootable USB first... **UNDER WINDOWS**  for Pete's sake! Can't Linux/Ubuntu do its own tools?
This is ludicrous. I should be able to download the upgrade and just run it, apply it. Update manager should be able to pull it down. I shouldn't have to dump it off to other off-line media to run it.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Since none of the suggestions above worked, this is how you currently resolve this issue:

Order the install CD from Ubuntu.

Most of the responses to this question  were not thought out, but Q'N'D, boilerplate, fire from the hip, and ended up wasting my time.